# Where should two adjectives of the BAGS type be placed in a noun phrase?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, syntaxe

I am wondering if there is a rule to follow when using in a noun phrase two adjectives that fall under the BAGS category? For example, in English, "a big beautiful house" is correct but "a beautiful big house" is not.